# Stack Comparison

Tags: app, website, stackoverflow

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image]

### About

This app helps you make decission when choosing a technology for your next cool project, by providing you stats about community engagement - knowing how many questions got asked and how many of them were answered for a particular technology can give you a rough idea about possible support in future when you'll have trouble with something.
I've created this app for my own purpose when I had to choose a js framework for client side, but quickly realised that this could be useful for other developers.
It performs search queries to /questions and /questions/unanswered with tags= and filter=. Then it caches the results in my database and presents them as infographics: the larger the circle the more questions it found, and the greener it is the higher ratio of answered questions (while red color indicates unanswered questions).

#### License

It's available for free on my website.

#### Download

http://stackcomparison.vanisoft.pl/index.php

#### Platform

Should work in any browser.

### Contact

qbolec@gmail.com

### Code

PHP, mysql, bootstrap.css, cURL.
The code is ugly, and dead simple, but I am too shy to present it to you.